# Precal Jump or Point discontinuity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, continuity, rational-functions

[image]

This is a precal homework problem I don't really get...

At $x=-3$, I thought that I couldn't determine whether it was a point of jump discontinuity, because though it is clear that the value of $x=-3$ is different from its (left-side) limit, after $x=-3$, the function's value could have come back down to near $2$ (that would be point discontinuity), or it could simply be jump. However, the answer says it is jump discontinuity only. How can I be so sure?

Comment: A rational function is continuous on its domain.  If you want to speak of non-domain points as discontinuities (questionable), they will be removable discontinuities or infinite discontinuities.  A rational function can't have two different finite one-sided limits at a point; and so it is hard to see anything on a rational function being called a jump discontinuity.

Comment: I don't get it either.  If $S=\{x_j: 1\leq j\leq n\}$ is a finite set of $n$ numbers, then, given $\{y_j:1\leq j\leq n\},$  there are (infinitely many) polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(x_j)=y_j$ for $1\leq j\leq n. $ So for $0\ne A$ and $\{A,-A\}\cap S=\phi$,  let $R_A(x)=p(x)+(x-A)^{-2 }\prod_{j=1}^n(x-x_j)$ for $x\in \mathbb R$ \ $\{A,-A\}$.  Then $R_A$ cannot be extended to a continuous real function. But you cannot uniquely identify $\{-A,A\}.$ You are only given a finite table of values. It does not say that $\lim_{x\to (-3)^+}R(x)=2.$